# Inspect WKWebview for app running on Mac Designed for iPad

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, safari, inspect

I have been working on an app which run on iOS Device and Mac both. I'm using Mac Designed for iPad option. I want to inspect WKWebview from my app in safari. I am able to inspect WKWebview in iOS devices but not able to inspect the same using Mac device as my app is not getting listed under develop option in safari for Mac Designed For iPAD option.